# How to properly add elements to ConcurrentHashMap in multiple threads using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to load images from some folder to ConcurrentHashMap using multiple threads to save time. Unfortunatelly,  some threads 'getting stuck' while they are trying load and put image to my map. As a result, when calling shutdown() program goes further even if some threads didnt perform their tasks. When I set the ExecutorService threads pule to 1, everything goes properly but I waste a lot of time waiting to load all images. It seems to me that there is some race problems but as I know ConcurrentHashMap is safe for multithread operations. I'm still a beginner so please let me understand where is the problem and what I'm doing badly.
Here is the code:

```
public abstract class ImageContainer {

private final static Map<String, BufferedImage> imageMap = loadImages();
private static long loadingTime;

public static Map<String, BufferedImage> loadImages() {

    loadingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, BufferedImage> imageMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    File imageDirectory = new File("Images/");
    if (!imageDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Image directory error");
    }
    File[] files = imageDirectory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                es.submit(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".jpg")) {
                                imageMap.put(file.getName().replace(".jpg",""),ImageIO.read(file));
                            }
                            else if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".png")) {
                                imageMap.put(file.getName().replace(".png",""),ImageIO.read(file));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Cannot load image");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Image folder empty!");
    }

    es.shutdown();
    try {
        if(!es.awaitTermination(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("Images did not load successfully!");
            es.shutdownNow();
        }
        loadingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - loadingTime;
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Loading images interrupted!");
    }
    System.out.println(imageMap.size());
    return imageMap;
}
};
```

Comment: Tried the same with HashMap (not CHM) and worked without any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has most likely nothing to do with `ConcurrentHashMap`. Each time, you `put` something in the map, no other thread will be able to `put` concurrently. So maybe, some threads will have to wait until the other has finished with `put`, but that will not cause any race conditions.

I executed your code on my machine and everything is working. (No error message, prints the number of loaded images). Maybe your computer is not as fast as mine in loading images and therefor, the `awaitTermination` times out.

As far as I can tell, I don't know if your approach (loading images with multithreading) is such a good idea. Your harddrive (or SSD) will be the bottleneck and your threads will end up waiting for the hard drive (statement `ImageIO.read`).
Also, spinning up an executor service (resp. starting new threads) is not very cheap, so maybe you're better of without multithreading. Especially because you only need to load the images once (after, they are cached in the map), so the speedup will probably never be significant. I would consider loading the images sequential.

Comment: Thanks for reply and testing my code. I tried with different times of awaitTermination and that was not a source of problem . But in the meantime I started to check how the number of thread affects for program. Probably the reason is that sometimes I got the number of images similar to number of running threads e.g. 5 images and 5 threads and then I experience some errors. In other cases, when the number of images is much bigger than number of threads, everythings works good.

Answer (score 0):

ImageIO is pretty slow and very I/O intensive so adding many threads often won't help on typical PCs. Are you sure that you just don't need to add a large number for awaitTermination timeout?

Another option is to use LinkBlockingQueue with a limited length for the thread pools so that your main application thread slows down when the consumers are slow. That means the time delay 5L seconds at the end is realistic to allow calls in progress to end.

See JDK source for newFixedThreadPool(n), try a qSize = say 2 or 3 x nthreads in the contructor to LinkedBlockingQueue()

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```